# tune rrd to increase step and heartbeat (x2)

Tags: rrdtool

I've got a bunch of rrds being updated every 5min

```
step = 300
ds[ExeTime].minimal_heartbeat = 600
```

I need to change this to every 15min.

rrdtool tune allows me to change the heartbeat but not the steps.  Can I simply change the heartbeat to 1800? (900 = 15min .. then x2 for heartbeat) ??

Will this leave a bunch of holes making avg/max/etc off?

Answer (score 1):

The Heartbeat only specifies the amount of time that can pass between two consecutive updates for rrdtool to still consider the time BETWEEN the updates to contain valid data. So if you simply want to be able to only update the rrd file every 15 minutes instead of every 5, then changing the heartbeat is sufficient.

On the other hand, if you want to change the way the data is stored in the rrd file, they you may want to give rrdtool 1.5 (rc2 at the moment) a whirl, it has a greatly enhanced rrdtool create function that allows you to setup a new rrd file and pre-populate it with data from an existing rrd file. The structure of the two files does NOT have to be the same.